# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las condiciones de estos if?

Tags: java, condiciones

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre estas condiciones?

```
entero x;
        si (x<=0 && x>=10) {
        }
        si((x<=0) && (x>=5)){
            
        }
```

Comment: Dejando de lado la parte obvia, no hay diferencia, el resultado de ambas expresiones es falso. Los paréntesis agrupan expresiones y pueden cambiar el orden de evaluación pero como solo hay una expresión dentro del paréntesis es como si no estuviera.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no son diferentes el resultado es el mismo en una condición usar `()` lo que indicas es, qué se tiene que evaluar primero, ejemplo:

```
entero x = 10
si ((x == 10 || x == 20) && x != 2)
```

En esta situación lo que se evalúa primero es saber si x es igual a 10 o 20 y este resultado se compara con las siguientes condiciones.